# Deleted content from contents folder but application size unchanged

Tags: mac, storage

My Google Chrome was taking up 14GB of storage. A bit of research later I found that the problem was likely that Chrome was not deleting old versions of itself. That was exactly the problem. I went into the contents folder and deleted 13GB of old versions. I restarted Chrome and my mac but Chrome is still taking up the full 14GB of storage. Any ideas on how to force the space to become free?

Comment: Did you empty the Trash?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by adding a new folder in the contents folder and then deleting it. This changed Chrome to 500mb. It didn't immediately clear the space in About This Mac, but I think that fixed itself at some point later.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).